# Why do they make the [r] sound between words when speaking?

Tags: pronunciation, spoken-english, parts-of-speech

> https://youtu.be/YozWDsiKQUk?t=6m5s

(6:05) Here, the reverend is saying "I feel like I'm experiencing something that's really nice with Nutella in it." But for me it actually sounds like "**Nutellar** in it."

(6:33) again, the woman is saying "but Netella is great", but it sounds like "but **Nutellar** is great."

And I couldn't find the clip, but in the TV show "Anne with an E", Marilla says 
"and be good friends with Diana again", but it actually sounds like "be good friends with Dian**ar** again."

I often hear these [r] or [ar] sounds when natives speak English. What is this?
Is this just their habits or Do they often do this to pronounce easier or something?

Comment: Bostonians do this, too. I'm amazed, sometimes, at the little things learners pick up on that we natives hardly notice.

Comment: You can find good answers in [this question at ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32619/why-is-idea-sometimes-pronounced-as-idear).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is 'idea of' pronounced 'idearof'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/152954/is-idea-of-pronounced-idearof)