# Is 'idea of' pronounced 'idearof'?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, phonology, connected-speech

This may sound absolutely crazy but I really need an answer to that.

How do natives pronounce "idea of"

I am not sure if I hear it correctly, but to me, it seems like when natives pronounce 'idea of' they add an extra 'r' to the pronunciation. So I hear something like 'idear of'. If that is true, why do they do that?

Comment: I would say (off the record) that most of us Americans would consider the r-sound at the end of "idea" as a regional accent and not as the correct pronunciation. I imagine that most people who pronounce "idear" would agree, as would most people who do not. I don't know what rule explains the fact that some people attach the r-sound to this word but not to other, apparently similar words. But you may have no reason to try to imitate this habit by including r's wherever this accent would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Preliminaries

- **Rhotic & non-rhotic accents:** A rhotic accent is one in which the R is pronounced in all contexts (i.e. beginning, middle and end of a word). General American English is rhotic. Non-rhotic accent, by contrast, is one in which the R is only pronounced when it precedes a vowel. Standard Southern British English is non-rhotic.
- **Hiatus:** It's the separation of the sounds of two consecutive vowels that occur in adjacent syllables. For example, pronounce *idea of* as [aɪdɪə_əv] without an intrusive consonant.
- **Connected speech:** Connected speech is spoken language in a continuous sequence i.e. a continuous stream of sounds without clear-cut borderlines between words.

### Intrusive consonants

In connected speech, we try to link the vowels and consonants in order to provide a hiatus. When a word ends with one vowel and the next word starts with another vowel, it can result in a hiatus, so we put an epenthetic consonants in order to join those words. There are three main types of linking consonants:

**1. Intrusive /j/:** When one words ends in /i/, /aɪ/, /ɔɪ/, /eɪ/, and the next word begins with a vowel, there's often a glide /j/ between them. For instance, *he is* is pronounced [hiː**j**ɪz] rather than [hiː ɪz] in connected speech.

**2. Intrusive /w/:** When one word ends in /u/, /aʊ/, /əʊ/ etc., and the next word begins with a vowel, English speakers are likely to insert an intensive /w/, as in *go away*, pronounced [ɡəʊ**w**əweɪ].

**3. Intrusive /r/:** When one word ends in /ə/, /ɔː/, /ɑː/, /ɪə/ etc., and the next word begins with a vowel, most non-rhotic speakers will insert an epenthetic /r/ as in:

- idea of → [aɪˈdɪə**ɹ**əv] (*idea/**r**/of*)
- idea about → [aɪˈdɪə**ɹ**əbaʊt] (*idea/**r**/about*)
- saw a film → [sɔː**ɹ**əfɪɫm] (*saw/**r**/a film*)
- law and order → [lɔː**ɹ**ənɔːdə] (*law/**r**/and order*)

'Intrusive /r/' is increasingly common in British English. You'll also hear it after proper nouns, for instance, *Obama/**r**/administration*, *Stella/**r**/and stellar* etc.

Note, however, that when there's an R in the spelling as in *far away*, the /r/ is called 'linking /r/', when there isn't, it's called 'intrusive /r/'.

---

<sup>/j/ is the 'y' in **y**ou, /w/ is the 'w' in **w**ine, [ɹ] is the English R sound as in **r**ing</sup>

Answer (score 2):

This is called an *intrusive R*, and occurs in some non-rhotic accents of English, such as standard British English. It would not occur in rhotic accents such as a general American accent.

Basically, the final vowel of "idea" (the schwa) is pronounced the same as many words that end with an "R" in English in non-rhotic accents. Thus, when the a vowel follows the word "idea", or any word that ends with a schwa, the "R" is added back in. With many speakers of non-rhotic accents, this occurs with words that never historically had an "R" sound, such as "idea".

There is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_and_intrusive_R) about this phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

*Eye-dear ov*.

Now you have to find out how I pronounce "eye", "dear" and "ov" ...

OK, seriously, [idea](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/idea#Pronunciation) and [idea](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/idea) aren't far off, although I know my pronunciation has a hint of a 'y' between the ɪ and the ə.

Similarly [of](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/of#Pronunciation) and [of](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/of) are close enough IMO.

Comment: haha, I know about those. but why 'dear' and not 'dea'? Is there a rule?

Comment: Also, I have noticed the same thing for "the idea is". I hear them say it as if it is "the idear is" ...

Comment: The "r" isn't really there, it's kind of a ... linking sound between the end of the "-ea" of "idea" and the "o-" of "of". Much like the French slip a *-t-* between some words, or a passing note in music, I guess. Cannot remember the technical term, don't think it particularly matters for this question ...