# Pronunciation of "idea" as "idier"?

Tags: pronunciation, connected-speech

Why do some people pronounce "idea" like "idier"?
Sometimes they do the same thing with some other words too.

Comment: "What" is the pronunciation can be answered in a dictionary.  "Why" is the pronunciation is not answerable, execpt to say "it just is".

Comment: It's answerable if strange and not recorded in dictionary

Comment: It should be closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/271486/106592)

Comment: It's a very unclear question, but I eventually came to understand it to be about the so-called "intrusive /r/" - which is well covered by Void's answer to the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply a fact of English pronunciation in certain parts of the world.

In southern England, for instance, there is a regional habit of pronouncing words that end in 'a' to sound like 'er'. So:

> Pasta/Pastor sound the same
>
> Santa/Santer
>
> Idea/Idier

Outside of southern England, I do not think it is very common. As someone who grew up in the southern UK, I know that North Americans find it both confusing and humorous.

Comment: I heard it from a New Zealander guy.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but Australia/New Zealand do seem to have some characteristics of a southern English/London-area accent. Purely anecdotal, but I remember an actor saying 'The best way to do an Australian accent is to say a cockney accent as if you're squinting at a bright sun'.

Comment: Words that end in 'a' don't sound like 'er'... Your answer is kind of misleading. See [my answer to another question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/271486/106592).

Comment: Yeah I know about the whole rhotic/non-rhotic thing. My point is I've experience (and been accused of using) a kind of non-rhotic hypercorrection. A bit like working class Londoners used to be accused of both dropping and adding aitches when they were attempting to sound 'posh'. Eg: "I 'ave never hunderstood 'ow ter huse haitches." It was a bit of a cliche, but based on a real phenomenon. So - I know I could pronounce a word like 'pastor' to sound like "pasta", but equally "pasta" to sound like "paster" (more of an -er than -or sound). Note also 'how ter/how ta' ... 'to' often gets 'er' added.