# Teacher pronunciations — /ˈtiː.tʃə(r)/ and /ˈtiː.tʃɚ/

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, phonology, ipa

Why Cambridge English dictionary gives two pronunciations for "teacher" and Lexico gives only one?

[Teacher](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/teacher) (CED):

- /ˈtiː.tʃər/ and /ˈtiː.tʃɚ/

Teacher ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/teacher)):

- Only /ˈtiːtʃə/

Does teacher have two pronunciations?

Comment: If one reputable dictionary has one, and another, even more reputable, two, then why should you assume that one of the ones given is ‘fake’?

Comment: Actually Lexico has two pronunciations, but you can't see both at once. You have to switch between the UK and US versions of Lexico.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In non-rhotic<sup>**1**</sup> varieties of English (Standard Southern British English here), 'teacher' on it's own is pronounced **/ˈtiː.tʃə/**. However, when it's followed by another word beginning with a vowel, it's pronounced /ˈtiː.tʃər..../ i.e. the R is pronounced.

Dictionaries often write it with a parenthetical or a superscript R<sup>**2**</sup> to indicate that the R is pronounced when followed by a vowel

- **/ˈtiː.tʃə(r)/**
- **/ˈtiː.tʃə<sup>r</sup>/**

**Example:**

- Teacher → /ˈtiː.tʃə/
- Teacher and students → [tiːt͡ʃe.ɹən.stjuːdn̩ts] (here the R is pronounced because it's followed by 'and' which begins with a vowel and that's what the superscript or parenthesised R indicates).

On the other hand, **/ˈtiː.tʃɚ/** is the General American English pronunciation of 'teacher'. GenAmEn is rhotic, meaning the R is pronounced in all positions.

In General American English pronunciation, the vowel /ə/ merges with the /r/ to form a single vowel called [r-coloured vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-colored_vowel): /**ɚ**/.

Lexico only gives the BrEn pronunciation, while Cambridge gives both BrEn and AmEn pronunciations.

---

**Notes:**

1. 'Non-rhotic' varieties are ones in which the R is only pronounced when it's followed by a vowel.
2. That R is often called '[linking R](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/271486/106592)'.